# jQuery doesn't take https url

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, https

I have a problem doing Ajax calls over https.

I'm using a self-hosted WebAPI, that listens on port 9000. The `index.html` page is loaded correctly, but the call to the api is suddenly *http* again.

I've looked everywhere in the JavaScript code, but I have only given the https-url once. Is it a cache problem? The problem occurs in Firefox, IE and Chrome, so I hardly believe that. Does jQuery prepare the call before doing it?

The last piece of code where the url seems to be right is here:

```
/**
 * Makes an HTTP GET request.
 * @method get
 * @param {string} url The url to send the get request to.
 * @param {object} [query] An optional key/value object to transform into query string parameters.
 * @param {object} [headers] The data to add to the request header.  It will be converted to JSON. If the data contains Knockout observables, they will be converted into normal properties before serialization.
 * @return {Promise} A promise of the get response data.
 */
get: function (url, query, headers) {
    return $.ajax(url, { data: query, headers: ko.toJS(headers) });
}
```

This is the console error:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at data.responseText to see why it is failing when its trying to parse it?

Comment: I sympathize with your situation, but all we have to go on is the text in your question, from which we could only *guess* at the cause. You'll have to further debug this yourself, and get back with more details if you have a repro you still need help with.

Answer (score 0):

I found it: unfortunately the development environment goes to another directory than the testing environment... so there was just the wrong url.